# .Net producing CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I need to create a CSV file in C#

I could do this myself and I have a java utility I wrote to do this as a reference. However it would be easier to use an existing .net library or utility. Do any such libraries/utilities exists?

Comment: Porting your Java code to C# could be fun :)

Comment: Fair point! But I probably won't have time :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question is pretty, I think it is worth adding information about **CsvHelper** library.

**CsvHelper** is a library for reading and writing CSV files. Extremely fast, flexible, and easy to use

- Source code available on [github](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) repository under [Microsoft Public License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL).
- Available as a nuget package [CsvHelper](http://nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper)
- Ability to [map](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Attribute-Mapping) custom class properties to CSV fields (by field names, indexes, with custom type converters) - personally think this is one of the best features.
- Custom type converters (works with CSV read and write operation)
- Supports LINQ
- Supports different versions of .NET i.e. `2.0`, `3.5`, `4.5`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExportClassLibrary.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Usually the problems lie with the reading/parsing of the CSV; writing/creating is more straightforward.

I shall not re-invent the wheel, here's a sample:
[A simple CSV generator from Dataset in C#](http://imduff.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/a-simple-csv-generator-from-dataset-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few libraries that will help with writing. [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a library I maintain) can take your objects and write them to a CSV file automatically for you.

```
var myCustomObjects = new List<MyCustomObject>{ ... };
var csv = new CsvHelper( File.OpenWrite( "file.csv" ) );
csv.Writer.WriteRecords( myCustomObjects );
```